# Toggle Leaflet sidebar V2

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, sidebar

so im really enjoying using this sidebar but battling to either toggle the sidebar or at least read the sidebar status so can .open() or .close() accordingly. Version 1 allowed siderbar.toggle(); - https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar

Dont seem to be able to find it on version 2 - https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin adds the `collapsed` class to the sidebar when it is collapsed, so you can use that to check its status. Borrowing a function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898748) to check whether an element has a particular class (and assuming that your sidebar div has the id `sidebar`), you can toggle it like so:

```
var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar').addTo(map);
var sidebarDiv = document.getElementById('sidebar');

toggleSidebar = function() {
  if (hasClass(sidebarDiv,'collapsed')) {
    sidebar.open();
  } else {
    sidebar.close();
  }
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

Example fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/gpqbvs50/

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so so much Nathan.

Comment: Using the above code, how would you add another sidebar?