# a click function that runs "if" then proceedes

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

what im trying to write is a function that will be activated by a click that will run if the class name of the clicked element is correct. then change the class name to another state so it can not be run again until another part of the function reverts it. it will roughly look like this:

```html
king1.addEventListener("click", turn);

function turn() {
 if (this.className="nf") {
  this.className="f"
   ...run more functions after
 };
 
}
```

Comment: `=` equals assignment. `==` / `===` equals comparison.

Comment: This is the second post I found with same problem. `=` means assignment. Use `==` or `===` to compare

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class. Not marking duplicate as the real issue is use of operator

Answer (score 3):

Use `classList` property of the element with [**includes#Array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or it's own [**contains**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) functions.

```
if([...classList].includes('nf')){

}
```

or

```
if(classList.contains('nf')){

}
```

Comment: i get this error in chrome " uncaught type error!: cannot read property 'contains' undefind

Comment: Check why is your `classList` undefined?

Comment: sorry, ima nub, is there a way to do this? my code so far is


 if (this.contains("nf")) {
 }