# js: element.className does not work (create a dark mode)

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to change the css properties of many html objects (but in this example I only took `body` to simplify. My goal is to display dark mode if the current mode is light, or display light mode if current mode is dark.
My javascript function does not work.

**debug.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="debug.css">
    <script src="darkmode.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body id="bodyElem" class="my-body light-mode">

      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <p>Dark mode:</p>

      <button type="button" onclick="invertMode()">click</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

**debug.css**:

```
.my-body.light-mode{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.my-body.dark-mode{
  background-color: black;
}
```

**darkmode.js**:

```
function invertMode() {
  var body = document.getElementById("bodyElem");
  var currentClass = body.className;
  body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";
}
```

Comment: you can use queryselector

Comment: Just use document.body to get body obj. Them check classes with classList or/and className, to toggle or change or whatever  body class.

Comment: ok but it's an example, in my real code it's not body i need to acces like i did

Comment: Ok so use just as godfather said, querySelector or querySelectorAll.  if you Need it change a lot of elements the approach Is right, change class to the body, and use that class into css change descendant elements styles.

Comment: my problem is that I have two classes in body but I do the `body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";` verification with only one class so it does not work but I don't know how to check it

Comment: If you have more class on body use classList to check what class/es is in there, than change (add/remove) according to your Wish. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add an `ID` for the `<body>` tag to be able to find it using your code.

```
<body id="bodyElem" class="light-mode">
```

and access it using:

```
var body = document.getElementById("bodyElem");
```

If you need to access mutiple elements, you can use their CSS class name like:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAMEHERE");
```

then loop them all to apply the changes you need.

you will be using `.classList.remove("CLASSNAME")` to remove single class and `.classList.add("CLASSNAME")` to add single class to DOM element

Here is a complete sample fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j3o8Lt5k/1/

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question because I want to do it in another way also.

Comment: that was not exactly my second question. Look at my edited code

Comment: does the `body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";` overwrite the `class="my-body light-mode` or it simply adds the class after ?

Comment: @MikeDelta updated my answer with working example. and no, the new sample only remove or add one class without affecting others.