# How to check if ALL objects of specific class share another class as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if all objects of `classA` share also `classB`. However, with the following code, it throws `true` if *at least one* object has the `classB`:

```
$(".classA").hasClass("classB")
```

How can I check if **all** elements with `classA` also have `classB`? (with either jQuery or plain Javascript)

Comment: `$('.classA').length == $('.classA.classB').length` …?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an array, and use `Array.prototype.every`:

```
const everyAHasB = [...document.querySelectorAll('.classA')]
  .every(a => a.classList.contains('classB'));
```

There's no need to require a big library like jQuery for something this simple.

Comment: Getting an error: `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`

Comment: @AhsanKhurshid You must be using an extremely ancient browser which doesn't support `classList`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript for alternative methods

Comment: I am using the latest browser `Google Chrome: Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: You may verify here by clicking the link: https://codepen.io/ahsanrathore/pen/KLZwNY?editors=1010

Comment: You forgot to spread the `querySelectorAll` into the array. Use `[...document`, not `[document`

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let hasClass = true;
$(".classA").each(function(){
  hasClass = hasClass && $(this).hasClass("classB")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var c = $(".classA").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).hasClass("ClassB");
})
```

This will return those elements that don't have `ClassB`

If you want to get all the Elements that has both classes, just remove the `!` from `!$(this)`

**Demo**

```js
var c = $(".classA").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).hasClass("ClassB");
})

console.log(c)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="classA ClassB"></div>
<div class="classA ClassB"></div>
<div class="classA ClassB"></div>
<div class="classA"></div>
<div class="classA ClassB"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all elements and check for each of them:

```
let all=true;
$(".classA").each((el) => {
    if(!el.hasClass("classB")) all=false;
})

console.log(all)
```

Comment: I think `el` will be a DOM element rather than a jQuery object. Maybe `$(el).hasClass(...)`.