# find whether all element contains same class or not

Tags: javascript, html

There is `form-group` class in different div. But some of them contains `form-group success` and some contains `form-group error` class.

The class `success` and `error` are added from JavaScript

I want to log any text in console if all those div finally have `form-group success` class.

I tried this

```js
const formGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group')

  formGroup.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.className === 'form-group success') {
      console.log('cool')
    }
  })
```

But it is logging even if single div contains `form-group success` class.
I want to log only when all div having `form-group` class have `form-group success`

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if ALL objects of specific class share another class as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251354/how-to-check-if-all-objects-of-specific-class-share-another-class-as-well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go another way. Rather than checking the 'success' class for all (form-group)s check if any form-group has an 'error' class or not. This way you don't need to loop over an extra array.

```js
const formGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group.error')

if(!formGroup.length) console.log('No error!!')
```