# How to check if html tag contains a class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JS to check if an html tag contains a specific class

What I have so far (doesn't work)

```
if (html.classList.contains('test')) {

}
```

```
<html class="test">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript

Comment: What is `html` in this context? If it does point to this <html> element, then that should work: https://plnkr.co/edit/rZvNJZ3JThP1LQaHtOb6?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the class within the classList of the element.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('html');
var classList = el.classList;
console.log(classList.contains('test')); // gives true
```

```html
<html class="test">
```

You can also grab the className (which is a string of all applied classes and use .indexOf();

```js
let el = document.querySelector('html');
var className = el.className;
console.log(className); // gives 'test test2'
console.log(className.indexOf('test') > -1); // gives true
```

```html
<html class="test test2">
```

If you have access to jQuery, the .hasClass() method is what you want

```js
let test = $('html').hasClass('test');
console.log(test); // gives true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html class="test">
```

Comment: Your first snippet is what they are doing. Can you explain why it didn't work for them?

Comment: @Kaiido - hey good point - i didn't actually notice that :) - my guess is that they are not defining the html element (like I do with let el = document.querySelector('html');)and so there is no context for the classList.

Comment: Yes that's also my "guess", hence my close-vote as missing an [MCVE] since we can only "guess" what's wrong. (note that this element is accessible through `document.documentElement` property)