# How to check if an element class child has a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I read some topics about this before but this is the first time I try to apply it, but I got quite confused about how to check if some element has a class child and add some new class into it.

let say I want to add an `active` class to a `li` element child after click it. This is step by step that I want to do:

1. Check if there is an active class in the `li` element after clicking it
2. if there is none then add `active` class and if it already there then `return` or do nothing

for **number 1** I read this topic [check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript) but I quite confused of how to check in a child

and for **number 2** I already make the function for it but I quite confused where I must put it in my code

this is my html:

```
<li id="test" class="additional-menu"><a href="#">Link1</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

this is my css:

```
.active{
  color: red
}
```

this is my js to check the child:

```
// This is for check a normal class but I doesn't know how to check a child class element from this

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

var el = document.getElementById('test');

alert(hasClass(el, 'active'));


// I can use this function if it inside button using onClick
// But I got quite confused of how to use it without button

function addClass () {
    var x = document.getElementsById("test")[0]; 
    x.className += ' active';
}
```

Can someone help me to understand this? for your imagination, I want to make a navbar using this and the class still there when I move to a different routing let say if I'm in `home` I want the class to stay in `home` and if I'm in `career` I want the class to stay in there. I feel like I already there to solved it but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly attached click listener to immediate parent of all your click
  elements.
- Then remove the "active" class by looping through all the children's elements.
- Finally, add active class to the target you received in the click event itself

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  // event attached to parent for getting clicks of all child while bubbling
  document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default "a" tag redirect
    
    let target = event.target;
    
    if(target.tagName != "A"){
      return; // to make sure only <a> is been clicked
    }
    target = target.parentElement; //make related li as target now
    
    for(let li of target.parentElement.children){ //all child of parent ul
      li.classList.remove("active");
    }
    target.classList.add("active");
  });

});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<li id="test" class="additional-menu"><a href="#">Link1</a>
  <ul class="parent">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Wow thankyou it works, but can you explain it a little bit as from where the `click` come in `addEventListener("click"`  and is `tagName` the same as `className`?

Comment: About click, it can come in from any click/grandchild element of `<ul class="parent">` so we can cater all of them at once.   And tagName just gives you the HTML tag of an element [TagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_tagname.asp)