# Object contains class giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Tags: javascript

In my script I need to check if my newly created object inherits from a specific class. 
Found out this:

[Check if an element contains a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript)

I have tried to implement like this:

```js
class Testing {

}

let test = new Testing();
let elem = document.getElementById("result");
try {
  elem.innerHTML = test.classList.contains("Testing");
} catch (e) {
  elem.innerHTML = e;
}
```

```html
<span id="result">...</span>
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: `.classList` isn't a property of your `Testing` class. What class are you trying to check that it's a sub-class of?

Comment: A Javascript class is not the same as a HTML class attribute.

Comment: `classList` is a property of an HTMLElement ... class Testing isn't one of those

Comment: Your most likely after `test instanceof Testing`..

Comment: In my script there are more classes and a special static class. In the static class I want to push objects via a static method where I need to check if objects inherit from a specific class. In this simple code I need to check if these objects inherit from "Testing".

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition is empty, so obviously your `test` object doesn't have any property called `classList`, this is why you're getting this undefined error.

Otherwise, you could simply check if `test` is an object of the `Testing` class this way :

```
if (test instanceof Testing) {
  //do something
}
```