# How to make input sliders not overlap each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, rangeslider

There is this code, in it I set the minimum indent between the sliders using rangeGap. Everything seems to work as it should, but they continue to run into each other. Maybe someone can tell me what is wrong.

I can't figure out if it's the positioning of the elements or if I need to change the logic in the js. It should work like this, but the thumbs should not move each other when colliding: https://codepen.io/BabylonJS/pen/gqzBWx

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.slider--progress');
const inputMin = document.querySelector('.input--min');
const inputMax = document.querySelector('.input--max');
const inputRange = [inputMin, inputMax];

const rangeGap = 50000;

inputRange.forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    let minValue = parseInt(inputRange[0].value);
    let maxValue = parseInt(inputRange[1].value);

    if (maxValue - minValue < rangeGap) {
      if (e.target.className === 'input--min') {
        inputRange[0].value = maxValue - rangeGap;
      } else if (e.target.className === 'input--max') {
        inputRange[1].value = minValue + rangeGap;
      }
    } else {
      progressBar.style.left = (minValue / inputRange[0].max) * 100 + '%';
      progressBar.style.right = 100 - (maxValue / inputRange[1].max) * 100 + '%';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgb(42, 138, 42);
}

.slider--body {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider--progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider--inputs {
  position: relative;
}

.slider--inputs > input {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider--input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.4px;
  left: -3px;
  height: 5px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  background: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 138, 42);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Double-range slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider--body">
        <div class="slider--progress"></div>
        <div class="slider--inputs">
          <input type="range" class="slider--input input--min" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="250000" />
          <input type="range" class="slider--input input--max" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="750000" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="double-range-slider.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target.className === 'input--min'` will always return false. If you put `e.target.className` in a console log you will see `"slider--input input--min"`.

Here's the correct way for your condition  [Check if an element contains a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/check-if-an-element-contains-a-class-in-javascript/5898748)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help) Instead of **`className === 'class'`**, I wrote **`classList.contains('class')`** and it worked!

```js
const progressBar = document.querySelector('.slider--progress');
const inputRange = document.querySelectorAll('.slider--input');

let rangeGap = 50000;

inputRange.forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    let minValue = parseInt(inputRange[0].value);
    let maxValue = parseInt(inputRange[1].value);
    if (maxValue - minValue < rangeGap) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('input--min')) {
        inputRange[0].value = maxValue - rangeGap;
      } else if (e.target.classList.contains('input--max')) {
        inputRange[1].value = minValue + rangeGap;
      }
    } else {
      progressBar.style.left = (minValue / inputRange[0].max) * 100 + '%';
      progressBar.style.right = 100 - (maxValue / inputRange[1].max) * 100 + '%';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgb(42, 138, 42);
}

.slider--body {
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider--progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider--inputs {
  position: relative;
}

.slider--inputs > input {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slider--input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.4px;
  left: -3px;
  height: 5px;
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  background: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.slider--input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(42, 138, 42);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(107, 216, 107);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Double-range slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slider--body">
        <div class="slider--progress"></div>
        <div class="slider--inputs">
          <input type="range" class="slider--input input--min" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="250000" />
          <input type="range" class="slider--input input--max" min="0" , max="999999" step="10" value="750000" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="double-range-slider.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```