# HTML link with Ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I have 6 different links,and each link is going to call a different Ajax function.

I'm using the `<a href>` tag because I want it to appear as a link....Can I use this tag to call the Ajax function? or it only works with URL links?

THANKS!

Comment: yes you can ... as a matter of fact most ajax functions would use the href

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look this this: http://yensdesign.com/2009/06/safe-ajax-links-using-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can incorpore the link in the following way:
- on your link you can write `<a href="#" onclick="function()">...</a>`

Here you can see further information about this topic:

[What is the difference between the different methods of putting JavaScript code in an ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I call mine. I give my elements a class name such as 'clickable' then use Jquery's click function as so.

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
   //do ajax
});
```

Then in the function, I get the id of the element as so. `var id = this.id`, this will get the unique id of the element.

After that I use the `$.post` method of Jquery, the shorthand version of ajax and complete whatever call you need to make when the user clicks that link using the id.

Of course, in my case I never use the anchor tag, I just make is a button or apply the `. click` to the element I wish to add the ajax call to, but you could just surround the "link" in a span or a div to simulate the same effect.

Hope this helps in some way or another.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9440536/199364) is a code example of the jquery class-name approach. To clarify the first sentence and code snippet. (Would be useful to also have code example for the remaining paragraphs of this answer.)

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" onclick="function()">Text</a>
```

or even as they wrote, with jquery

```
<a href="#" id="blabla">Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function(){
  $('#blabla').click(function(){
  alert("Clicked");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the value of the `href` attribute and use it for your AJAX call...

(*it is actually the proposed way to handle it..*)

Comment: Could you please show an example of how to do this correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, if any client side script functions (javascript or jquery) applied than it will execute first.