# How do I transfer an onclick event in JavaScript from the inline script to an external file?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Inline script works, I just need to use onclick='document.getElementById("").innerHTML

However, I cannot get it to work in an external file. 
Do I need to define an onclick function -- something already
preset in HTML5?

Comment: Provide some code sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use external ".js" files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498068/how-to-use-external-js-files)

Comment: My first attempt at putting the code in didn't work. I'm simply trying to put W3 schools inline code into an external file: <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Click Me!</button>

Comment: This is probably related to page load order.  If your external script loads before the element exists, it will throw an error.  Either wrap your code in a DOMContentLoaded handler or put the script tag after the element that it uses.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple way of how it could be done:

**external.js**:

```
function myFancyOnClickHandler() {
     document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'something'
}
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="external.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="something" onclick="myFancyOnClickHandler()">Hello, World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

It's also possible to dynamically add an event listener with `addEventListener` like this (this way you don't need the `onload=""` attribute):

```
function myFancyOnClickHandler() {
     document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'something'
}

// This only works IFF the element is present in the DOM
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('click', myFancyOnClickHandler)
```

We can listen to the `window`'s `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event to be sure the DOM has loaded:

```
function myFancyOnClickHandler() {
     document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'something'
}

// This will work regardless of where we include the .js file
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('something')

    elem.addEventListener('click', myFancyOnClickHandler)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the event handler in an external js file, this is the syntax:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Where 'myBtn' is an id you can assign in html