# Link to submit a form in symfony2 doesn't valid the form

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

I've a form and I want to submit it from an link. Something like :

```
<form action="{{ path('update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" id="update" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
</form>

... some HTML

<a href="javascript:$('#update').submit();">Valid</a>
```

But when I submit the form using this link, the form is not validated in Javascript (check empty fields etc...) and don't display error tooltips

If I create a button in the form tag, it works, but i want this button outside of the form tag.

How can I do this ?

edit : My form is in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

not an ideal answer, but i guess this should work ...

have a submitbutton in your form,hide it using css

then where your current js link is, make it so that this uses jquery to simulate a click on the correct form-submit-button

Again, not ideal, but i guess it should do the job..

Answer (score 0):

This will work as you expected,

```
<script language="javascript">    
    $.fn.submitForm = function() {
        $('#update').submit();
    };    
</script>
```

and the call should be,

```
<a href="javascript:$(this).submitForm();">Valid</a>
```

But it is not appreciated to use javascript executions within `href`, look at [this previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code) discussion on this topic,

Then what i'm wondering is, since you are using Jquery why you are looking to trigger the submit within html `href`? , simply in a javascript file say script.js

```
//assuming there is only one <a></a> tag
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
   $('#update').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it another way.

To have the HTML5 field control, I have put an hidden submit button and I did;

```
$('#my_submit_button').click();
```

and it works.