# div is not displayed on click of image

Tags: javascript, image, html

I have an image at the top right corner of a page. on click of the image i have to display a div that looks like a table with many rows. The div has to be positioned exactly below the image.I have tried the below code snippet.

```
<div><a href="javascript:Test()"><img align=right src="Test.png" /></a></div>
```

sample code snippet for test function

```
Test(){
var hNode = document.createElement('div');
hNode.style.display = "block";
hNode.style.overflow="hidden";enter code here
hNode.style.position = "absolute"; 
hNode.style.width = "400px";
hNode.style.height = "30px";
hNode.style.border = "1px solid  #666666";
hNode .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
}
```

But the div does not show up.
What is wrong with this snippet? Any help would be great..

Comment: what does your debugger say? you're missing the `function` keyword before `Test()`. Adding that the function is called

Comment: you haven't added your new div to the dom; see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use an `onclick="Test()"` in your `<a>` tag

Comment: for completeness-sake... [there is debate as to best practices for triggering javascript in this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code)

Answer (score 0):

first : change `a` to `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Test();">link</a>`

second : in function implementation add `function` keyword before `Test()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div onclick="Test()"><img align=right src="Test.png" /></div>
```

may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test(){
   var hNode = document.createElement('div');
   hNode.style.display = "block";
   hNode.style.overflow ="hidden";
   hNode.style.position = "absolute";
   hNode.style.width = "400px";
   hNode.style.height = "30px";
   hNode.style.border = "1px solid #666666";
   var t = document.createTextNode("Test");
   hNode.appendChild(t)
   document.body.appendChild(hNode);
 }
```

while all the other answers are addressing problems with your code the answer as to why it doesn't appear is
you aren't actually appending the newly created `div` to `document.body` so although it exists it isn't part of the dom.

you can call this function using any of the methods described in other answers; i prefer something along the lines of

```
 <a href="javascript_policy.html" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">my link</a>
```

to direct users without javascript enabled to a page telling them why javascript is necessary for that particular link.