# Are button html tags outside of a form valid?

Tags: html, forms, button

I just noticed that, in soundcloud, the "action" buttons on a track (like, repost, etc...) are all html button tags. Moreover, they are neither inside a form nor they bind to a form a la html5 nor submit a form (they apparently are being handled through javascript). Is this valid HTML? Can a button exist without a form? Or does that just make these buttons plain clickable divs? And how valid/unvalid would that be for screenreaders?

Comment: Run it through a validator and see

Comment: Great comment... the documentation says also that the type of the button must be set because each browser handles it differently. Soundcloud doesn't set the type either. Should I rely on the validator for everything?

Comment: Not _everything_.... only rely on the "validator" to see if the code is "valid".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A `button` element is valid anywhere in the document body where text-level markup may appear. Such an element need not have any relationship to a `form` element. The currently authoritative reference is the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/), and the formal rules are in the DTD, but you can take a shortcut and use the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check whether a document is valid.

When not associated with a form, a `button` element is not very different from a `span` element (rather than `div`, which is block-level by default), but `button` has special default rendering. Browsers and assistive software *may* treat `button` as otherwise special too, and it is safest to use `button` only for elements that are supposed to trigger some action when clicked on. Conversely, such elements are often best represented using `button` markup, though you can create visually button-like elements in other ways too (images or CSS, mostly).

Outside a form, a `button` element has `type=button` as default (and that’s normally the only sensible `type` for it then). This means that it can only have an effect via JavaScript. This does not make it invalid in any way. However, you may consider generating such buttons via JavaScript instead of having them as static HTML content, so that when scripting is disabled, there won’t be a (valid, but) confusing button that does nothing.

To address clarifying questions in the comment below:

A `button type=button` element is similar to `input type=button`; the difference is that the latter has no content but takes the text shown in the button from the `value` attribute, whereas `button` has content that can be “rich” (with markup).

For either element, if using them causes a server action (typically, via an Ajax call), then we can indeed ask how the page works with JavaScript disabled. But this question might be irrelevant (perhaps the page is an application that is supposed to run with JavaScript anyway), and in any case there is nothing *formally* wrong with the idea.

Why do they exist? For author convenience and for legacy reasons, I would say. Similarly, one might ask why HTML has event attributes at all, when they cannot possibly work without client-side scripting and you can assign event handlers to elements in JavaScript. But in the early days, that was not possible, and even at present, it might be more convenient to use the `button` element or the `onclick` attribute than to do things in JavaScript (and, for making an element look like a button, CSS). There is also the point that `button` and `input type=button` create browser-dependent appearance for elements, and it might be argued that for most users, anything that has the style of his browser’s default style for buttons is perceived as a button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A few questions: can we say the button type=button would be the equivalent to the form input type=button? (namely, elements that natively don't do nothing)? If the action such a button triggers changes the state in the server (like, "liking" a song in soundcloud), is it correct to assume such a thing should have been done using a form instead, for the reason that such buttons don't work without javascript (forgot for now you can't hear songs without javascript either :) )? And for last, if such elements don't natively do anything, why do they exist in the first place?

Comment: While I agree with much of what you say in practical terms, I would disagree with your why. It makes total sense semantically to mark up an element such as a social icon as a button. The problem of handling disabled scripting is solved by techniques such as progressive enhancement. I particularly like the idea of generating the problem element in the script. However, in the case of ajax, at some point there is functionality that can't be replaced and that I don't want to be deprived of. Drag and drop, for instance. Or my beautiful dynamically generated treeview. I have to insist on the script.

Comment: It seems that at least some implementations will submit a form if you put a button outside it without `type=button`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825856/html-button-to-not-submit-form

Comment: @CiroSantilli, the question you refer to must be bases on a misunderstanding or on experiences with some old browsers that are no longer relevant.

Comment: "Outside a form, a button element has type=button as default (and that’s normally the only sensible type for it then)." I don't think this is true. The type defaults to "submit" whether it is inside or outside of a form element. Just because there is no form to submit doesn't mean the type of the button would change.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Since a very long time.

From [whatwg.org](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html) :

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> Where phrasing content is expected.

In the era of ajax, most inputs aren't just send by submitting a form. And most buttons are just used to execute an action on click while using a recognizable widget.

Comment: if a button click submits data to the server (like, for instance, "liking" the song) then I should be doing this through a form, I'd say. Not only that, as I mentioned in a previous comment, the buttons don't have a type. What does that make them? And I disagree that these specific buttons are "phrasing content".

Comment: I pasted from the doc, where phrasing content is [defined](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content). There isn't much reason today to use a form, which mostly adds constraints on what you submit. The form element is mostly an obsolete remaining of the past.

Comment: I fail to see where a button saying "like" is "the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level". Maybe it's just me. Saying that the forms only impose constraints is basically saying that doing it all with clickable divs and css would be also ok. Why do we check the validity of the documents then?