# How to disable redirecting when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I use Codeigniter and Bootstrap.

I have a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="btnid" href="http://site/controllerName/parameter">Text</a>
```

If I click to the button its call a controller with one parameter then the controller redirects to a site.

My question is that is there a way to call the controller with a parameter but skipping the redirection?

Comment: I could not find any `button` in your markup..

Comment: Sorry then, this is a simple link, but how should I disable the redirecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Add your event handlers inside ready block
    $("#btnid").click(function(event) { // button event handler
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from redirecting
          $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) { // send call
             // after call 
           });
    });
});
```

For details refer to - [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

**Edit**

As there are more than one link. You can use `class` selector. Currently, you have 2 classes `btn` and `btn-success`. You can use either of them, however, I will suggest you to add one more class let us say `btn-api`

Then update your click selector to

```
$(".btn-api").click(function(event)) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from redirecting
      $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) { // send call
         // after call 
       });
});
```

Comment: This is working. Where should I add my link address?

Comment: @V.Mark - link address? Sorry not clear with what you are asking. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: I think he wants to know where, in the ajax call, to add the link (url) to his controller, right V. Mark

Comment: @V.Mark - `$(this).attr('href')` is the url/link to the controller. Thanks unicorn2 for clarifying

Comment: There is a problem with that. This is only works with the first one element with #btnid  ID. In my page there are numerous link with the same ID. What should I do?

Comment: @V.Mark - No 2 elements can have same id. You can either add a class to all such elements and then in place of id selector in js use class selector for event binding

Comment: Could you write me an exapmle please? My buttons class: class="btn btn-success"

Comment: @V.Mark - I have updated the answer for your reference. Please check.

Comment: Thank you really much! You have made my day! :)

Comment: @V.Mark - Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ - prevents the default action

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Did you read this: _My question is that is there a way to call the controller with a parameter but skipping the redirection?_

Comment: @OrHarel - OP demands 2 things. 1. Send call. 2. Stop redirection. Your answer covers the 2nd point only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault();`
This is an exemple with just JavaScript (Not jQuery)

```
<script>
    function stopDefAction(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

    document.getElementById('btnid').addEventListener(
        'click', stopDefAction, false
    );
</script>
```

You can find documentation and complete exemple here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Incomplete answer..If you are not certain about the question then you can make use of comments section..

Comment: Why incomplete...? I think I answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript method which does a ajax call. Then there will be no redirect.

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="btnid" onclick="javascript:theFunction();" href="#">Text</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function theFunction () {
         event.preventDefault();
         // add your ajax call to the controller here e.g 
         $.ajax({
            url: "http://site/controllerName/parameter"
            }).done(function() {
                // action when the controller call returns 
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick="javascript:theFunction();"` ? Why so ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer I think it is well explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code

Comment: Why to use inline js event binding ? Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2zyshj4u/

Comment: Ah oki, yes I see now! No need then to hook the function to the onclick instead of the href.

Answer (score 0):

By default a click on the a link to a controller will either render this controller's view or redirect to another view. To stop redirecting, you must call the controller via AJAX. To fully understand this, lets see what happens when you don't use ajax:

1. You click on the link which triggers the request.
2. The request is routed to your controller.
3. The controller processes the request. The ending line of the controller is something like $this->load->view('your-view');
4. This loads the raw HTML after any view logic has been processed and sends it back to your browser via normal HTTP. This issues a redirect (or a refresh if it was the same page).

What AJAX does, is that it takes the data received in step 4, and makes it available in a variable via javascript. To see this, we can write a code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="getAjaxData()" class="btn btn-success" id="btnid">Text</a>
```

The easiest way to use ajax is via JQuery.
**Javascript**

```
    function getAjaxData(e) {
        // Make sure that the link default action doesnt occur.
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', // depending on the controller method.
            url: 'http://site/controllerName/parameter',
            success: function(data)
            {
                // The variable data contains the data returned from the controller.
            },
            error: function()
            {
                alert('Something went wrong!');
            }
        });
```

Now if you leave things as they are, the vairable `data` will contain the raw HTML returned from the controller. Usually if you will use AJAX, it is better to either return HTML snippets which you can append directly to your current HTML DOM, or return data in JSON format, which you can then process via javascript.

Comment: This is very well explained