# django button -> start script -> stay on same page (no redirects/no refresh)

Tags: python, django

Im working on a simple web app - that turns on a led on a arduino.

I'v got it working, but the problem is i dont want for the page to redirect/refresh after i press the button.

So once again; after i press the button i just want it to start a python script and dont redirect to a other page or refresh the current page.

Do i need to implement ajax or is there any other way? Tried some stuff with ajax but couldnt get it to work.

Code:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path(random_string(5), views.ledOn, name = "ledikaOn"),
    path(random_string(5), views.ledOff, name= "ledikaOff"),
    
    
# views.py

def ledOn(request):
    s.send(ledOnUkaz.encode('ascii'))  # to poslje kodo "ukaz ON" v server
    return render(request, 'home.html')
    
    
# home.html
    
<a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary" href="{% url 'ledikaOn' %}" role="button">LED ON</a>
```

Comment: look into `jquery`

Comment: Thanks @TomWojcik. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `href` attribute is wrapped in double quotes: `""` and `''`:

```
href="'{% url 'ledikaOn' %}'"
```

Change it to this:

```
href="{% url 'ledikaOn' %}"
```

Comment: Oups. Thanks for the notice. --repaired the original post

Comment: Don't ever do that again I wasted my 2 minutes.

Comment: @Shiv excuse me?

Comment: No, not you. I'm talking about @pampi. The guy just corrected the question and I think he shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Shiv you can see edits under questions and posts, that really shoudln't be a problem

Comment: @Shiv, The question wasn't corrected. Part of the code was. My question is still the same. The notice from SLDem doesn't change anything. I just had a typo in my code. Im still looking for a way to run a python script without redirecting/refreshing. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so You haven't got you answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so i figured it out. If anybody has the same problem, here's the solution:

Add this to your .js file:

```
    $("#btnid").click(function(event) { // button event handler
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from redirecting
      $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) { // send call
         href="{% url 'ledikaOn' %}"  // url to your page/views
       });
```

modify your .html file: ** i had to add -> id="btnid" <-

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary" id="btnid" href="{% url 'ledikaOn' %}" role="button">stissno</a>
```

i found the solution here:
[How to disable redirecting when clicking on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244195/how-to-disable-redirecting-when-clicking-on-a-button)

Best regards,
pampi