# how to disable routerLink for anchor tags

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Its an angular application. I need to make an image slider. The application has router link because of which the image slider anchor tag keeps getting redirected. Instead of calling the javascript function and sliding the images, it keeps getting redirected to router table. What can be used to stop the anchor tags from redirecting?.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code?

Comment: removing the routerLink form the html code does not work?

Comment: are you using Carousel?

Comment: why using anchors instead of buttons to trigger a non-navigation event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anchor tags that should only call a javascript function, you should remove the `routerLink` directive and disable any browser redirect, e.g. by setting `href='javascript: void(0)'` - you can find other possible solutions here, maybe one of the examples is able to help:

[What is the difference between the different methods of putting JavaScript code in an <a>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code)